# Where to store user data after login with WebForms

Tags: c#, session, cookies, authentication

I'm developing a WebForms web application with VS2010 in C#. I use my custom login approach to authenticate users and I don't want to use Membership framework. After user login I want to store user data as userId, username, surname, email, etc., so I can access them during the user session in all pages.

How can I do that? I don't wanna store user data in the `UserData` property of the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`.

I found this approach: [Should I store user data in session or use a custom profile provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832141/should-i-store-user-data-in-session-or-use-a-custom-profile-provider), but I don't understand how to implement it.

I have some question:
1)in my login page to authenticate user after check credentials on db  I use :  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Value, true);   now in my default page I have:
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ((FormsIdentity)(User.Identity)).Ticket;  and I use ticket.Name to show username. is it correct? why do you talk about thread using Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name ?
2) I have this code in global.asax file to  read user roles and store thems into HttpContext:

void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnStr"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Gruppi.Name FROM Ruoli INNER JOIN Gruppi ON Ruoli.GroupID = Gruppi.GroupID INNER JOIN Utenti ON Ruoli.UserID = Utenti.UserID AND Utenti.Username=@UserName", conn);      
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", User.Identity.Name);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ArrayList rolelist = new ArrayList();         
        while (reader.Read()){
            rolelist.Add(reader["Name"]);
        }
          //  roleList.Add(reader("Name"))           
        string[] roleListArray = (string[])rolelist.ToArray(typeof(string));
        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, roleListArray);

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

can I store user data into session as you wrote from my global.asax file rather then login.aspx page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interest of easier debugging, I suggest using the Session Facade design pattern, [described here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16656/Manage-ASP-NET-Session-Variables-using-the-Facade), that will allow you to store the current user's data using the `HttpContext.Current.Session` object in a more organized fashion.

For instance, there would be a file (e.g., `SessionFacade.cs`) that is responsible for handling the values passed to/from the `Session`; in your case, it might look like:

```
public static class SessionFacade
{
    public static int UserId
    {
        get {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] == null)
                HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = 0;
            return (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"];
        }
        set {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = value;
        }
    }
    // ... and so on for your other variables
}
```

Then, somewhere else in your code, once you check that credentials are okay, you can do...

```
if (credentialsAreOk) {
    SessionFacade.UserId = /* insert ID here */
    // ...
}
```

...instead of manually assigning values to the Session object. This ensures your variables in `Session` are of the correct type, and will be easier to track while debugging. Then, to get the UserId from anywhere in your program, it's just `SessionFacade.UserId`.

(yes that snippet was from Eduard's answer; you should still look into that answer as it is informative as to how WebForms work; just keep in mind that calling the `Session` object manually in your code can be quite messy and that the Session Facade makes that process cleaner)

Comment: thank you for your example code, I have a question for you: what is the difference between this approach (store data into asp session) and write a custom profile class?

Comment: Not too familiar with working with profile, but (correct me if I'm wrong) setting up a profile involves working with the Web.config file, while a Session Facade bypasses that. Both have a similar idea though: you won't be working with the Session object directly either way.

Answer (score 3):

In case that by "web application by VS2010 in C#" you're talking about ASP.NET (MVC or Classic) and by "custom login approach" you're referring to [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) then all you need to do is to store your later needed information at login time, onto the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) object.

Let's say you're using ASP.NET Classic and you have a login page

[image]

which has 2 inputs for Username and Password and a submit button entitled "Login"

[image]

In the button's (server side) OnClick event handler you should do something like this:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    private bool CheckUserPass(string username, string password) {
        // access DB or some other form of storage service
        return true;
    }

    protected void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        bool credentialsAreOk = this.CheckUserPass(
            this.textBoxUsername.Text,
            this.textBoxPassword.Text
        );

        if (credentialsAreOk) {
            this.Session["EMAIL_ADDRESS"] = "SomeEmail@SomeEmailProvider.com";
            this.Session["OTHER_INFORMATION_KEY"] = "Some other stuff which you have access to during the login process";
            this.Session["TIME_OF_LOGIN"] = DateTime.UtcNow;

            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(this.textBoxUsername.Text, createPersistentCookie: false);
        }

    }

}
```

So, in short, if you're using FormsAuthentication, then the username can be stored onto the session in the same way you're telling the FormsAuthentication system that current session should be transformed from non-authenticated to authenticated:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(this.textBoxUsername.Text, createPersistentCookie: false);
```

whereas other information can be placed on the Session object (just like you would add key value pairs to a Dictionary):

```
this.Session["TIME_OF_LOGIN"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

While it is obvious how you could later access that same information (for the respective user):

```
DateTime whenDidILogin = (DateTime) this.Session["TIME_OF_LOGIN"];
// this line of code can be used in any other page
// at any later time - it's like you have a global set of variables
// which exist for each and every distinct session you might have
```

it is maybe important to mention that the username (if not placed explicitly onto the Session object like the other examples) can be accessed by means of the [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx) static property like so:

```
using System.Threading;

public void SomeWhereInYourApp() {
    bool wasIAuthenticated = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    string whatIsMyUsername = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

    // do something with that information
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try your solution very soon, I have some question:<br>
1) now in my default page I have:   
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ((FormsIdentity)(User.Identity)).Ticket;

Comment: I think I can guess where you're going with your question. In my opinion, concerning yourself with the Ticket associated with the FormsAuthentication identity is a bit looking under the hood. Do you want to look under the hood at this time, or do you want a working app ? It so happens that FormsAuthentication knows all to well whether a request comes from someone or someone else. Actually you don't even need FormsAuthentication to disambiguate between different sessions. Short answer to your 1): I really think all you want is to obtain that info you mentioned in the question, not the cookie..

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try your solution very soon, I wrote some question in my first topic. I'm not well understanding what have you said in your last comment?

Comment: I'll try to make it simpler. What I said was this: You're trying to achieve a certain effect using a certain tool. You're trying to dry your hair using a hair dryer. You don't know how exactly you should use it: things like 1. plug it in, 2. find the ON/OFF switch and power it on... The Ticket property of the FormsIdentity class is somewhat .. electrical engineering. It is, at this stage at least, a detail of the inner workings of the electrical motor, inside the hair dryer. You needn't worry about magnetic coils, converting electricity into variable magnetic fields, etc. Just use the dryer :)

Answer (score 0):

[Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) provider helps you to store data and also for authentication purpose. Something like this:-

```
Session["UserName"] = Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

Comment: I don't want to use the Membership provider. I'm finding examples code to resolve my problem.

Comment: do you advice to store user data in the session ?

Comment: Please check this link:- http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/19/writing-a-custom-asp-net-profile-class.aspx